# Problem using multi part field to set values and files

Tags: karate

I have read the documentation and its described well but while I am using Multipart fields, it is not set the value as expected to send a file with fields

I have tried to create a multipart field and multipart file to set the values and uploaded the files

```
* def keyId5 = keyIds[4]
Given url baseUrl
  And path 'pds', 'fattr'
  And multipart field attributeName = "Passport"
  And multipart field keyId = keyId5
  And multipart file encryptedValue = { read: 'classpath:features/TestData/Passport1.jpg', filename: 'Passport1.jpg', contentType: 'multipart/form-data' }
  And header Content-Type = 'multipart/related'
 When method post
 Then status 200
```

I expect to send the fields of attributeName, keyId, and file as encryptedValue. But I am getting an error response from the API as 'Non-Zero value is required for keyId' (means the keyId is not set).

Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `keyId5` is not correct, so try hard-coding this.

If you are still stuck, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @perter Thomas  Thanks. keyId5 is dynamically created so I couldn't hard-code it. I printed the keyId5 to debug and it is printed the values.

Comment: @RajkamalS. I have nothing else to offer unless you provide a way for me to replicate, sorry.